# Querying two tables with different columns but one and with no relation between

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, `internal_mail` and `external_mail`, they relatively have different columns. I'm trying to select all records from both tables with ordering by a date column, called `date_of_arrival` in both tables.

For example this is `internal_mail`:

```
colunm 1          colunm 2          colunm 3          date_of_arrival
some_record       some_record       some_record       2017/8/12
.....             .....             .....             ..... 
.....             .....             .....             ..... 
.....             .....             .....             ..... 
.....             .....             .....             .....
```

And this is `external_mail`:

```
colunm A          colunm B          colunm C          date_of_arrival
another_record    another_record    another_record       2017/7/12
.....             .....             .....             ..... 
.....             .....             .....             ..... 
.....             .....             .....             ..... 
.....             .....             .....             .....
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is something like this(in case of a descending order by):

```
colunm 1  colunm 2  colunm 3  column A  column B  column C   date_of_arrival
s_r       s_r       s_r       empty     empty     empty      2017/8/12
empty     empty     empty     a_r       a_r       a_r        2017/7/12
s_r       s_r       s_r       empty     empty     empty      2017/8/12
empty     empty     empty     a_r       a_r       a_r        2017/7/12
```

Comment: what if the date matches? should you show them on one row?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala yes, if the date matches for both tables, all columns of the tables will be shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with `full join`. As MySQL doesn't support it, `union all` is your best option. Assuming you have to show the records on one row when the date matches in both the tables, you have to aggregate by date_of_arrival. If that isn't the case, leave out the aggregation and just use the inner query.

```
select max(column_1),max(column_2),max(column_3),max(columnA),max(columnB),max(columnC),date_of_arrival
from (select column_1,column_2,column_3,
      null as columnA,null as columnB,null as columnC,date_of_arrival
      from internal_email
      union all
      select null,null,null,columnA,columnB,columnC,date_of_arrival
      from external_email
     ) t
group by date_of_arrival
```

Comment: It only returns 4 rows.

Comment: Your solution works, precisely the inner query. However the full solution with showing all data in one row when the date matches for both tables doesn't, out of 61 records, it only returns 4.

Answer (score 1):

The first part is an easy UNION query, but you said you want to unify the rows if both tables have data for a given date. That would be achieved by `FULL OUTER JOIN` on the date, but MySQL doesn't support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

So here's an example (untested) of a workaround:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(column1) AS column1,
  MAX(column2) AS column2,
  MAX(column3) AS column3,
  MAX(columnA) AS columnA,
  MAX(columnB) AS columnB,
  MAX(columnC) AS columnC,
  date_of_arrival
FROM (
    (SELECT column1, column2, column3, 
       NULL AS columnA, NULL AS columnB, NULL AS columnC,
       date_of_arrival
     FROM internal_mail)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, columnA, columnB, columnC, 
       date_of_arrival
     FROM external_mail)
) AS t
GROUP BY date_of_arrival;
```

The GROUP BY is to combine rows with the same date into one row, even if both unioned tables have a row with the same date.

But we want this combined row to have the non-null values in each column. In a group of two rows for a given date, one row will have a non-null value, and the other row will have a null value. MAX() ignores the null, and takes the single other value. MIN() would have worked just as well, because it's choosing from a set of exactly 1 row, but I arbitrarily chose to use MAX().

Comment: What's the use of `MAX()` in this?